# Calling ant target in known xml file from within an Ant Task

Tags: java, ant

I'm writing an Ant Task:

```
public class MyTask extends Task {

    public void execute() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Now I'm wondering whether it is possible for me to call a target that exists in another known xml file from within the above execute() method?

Something like:

```
public void execute() {
    AntCaller.call("anotherBuildFile.xml", "someTarget");
}
```

Comment: Surely the easiest way to find out is to run the example code you've put up and see if it works? whats stopping you from doing that?

Comment: errr, AntCaller is a make-believe class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track.  If you wanted to all another task from XML, you would use `<ant>` (since it is another file.)  You can call a task from Java only if you have the .class file for it.  Luckily, you do have the .class file for the Ant task itself so you can use the same technique as you would in a build xml:

```
Ant helper = new Ant();
helper.setTarget("someTarget");
helper.setAntFile("anotherBuildFile.xml");
helper.execute();
```